# What does the JSHint 'nocomma' option do?

Tags: javascript, jshint

The [documentation says](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#nocomma):

> This option prohibits the use of the comma operator. When misused, the comma operator can obscure the value of a statement and promote incorrect code.

But it's still not clear to me what scenario JSHint is looking for. Could somebody please provide an example?

Comment: Do you not know what the comma operator is? Or do you not know how it could be misused? Is your question what the nocomma does? Or why it is there?

Comment: I didn't realize that `comma operator` was referring to a different concept than the `comma character` and it threw me off. If I recognized this then yes, I would have googled for `js comma operator` instead of `jshint nocomma option`.

Comment: @torazaburo: updated question to be more specific

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MDN: Comma Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

> The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

**Example**

```
function myFunc() {
  var message = "hello";

  return (message += "howareya", message);
}
// returns "hellohowareya"
```

Comment: This is not a complete answer without talking about how the comma operator can be misused and therefore why jshint is unhappy about it. By the way, the parentheses are unnecessary.

Comment: While unnecessary, I feel the parenthesis help illustrate the point that those are the two operands involved.

Comment: I think the answer is adequate since the question was to help clarify WHAT jshint looks for with this option. The WHY is certainly interesting, but could be a whole different question.